# Speed up your IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, performance

Is there any way to improve the performance of your IIS by changing some configuration parameters?

Or do you have any tips in general on how to improve the performance of a ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Remember to turn off 'debug' in the web.config
- don't use wildcard file mapping.
- Use httpCompression to improve perceived performance
- Throttle bandwidth to improve overall perceived performance
- Try use IIS7 for .net apps

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/71490aae-f444-443c-8b2a-520c2961408e.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: You should add Content Expiration to the list - nothing speeds up a web server then the local web browser cache :-)

Comment: Add disable sessions - they're slow and exclusively block concurrent requests on the server.

Answer (score 7):

Your first port of call should be here:-

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into Caching? or micro-caching Take a look at http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=85.

Answer (score 4):

On the other hand, you may try [IIS Tuner](http://iistuner.codeplex.com) open source tool for optimization

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the IIS Server there are several things you can modify with it including:

[HTTP Compression](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d52ff289-94d3-4085-bc4e-24eb4f312e0e.mspx?mfr=true) - Great for static content like JS and CSS files.

[Disable Logging (Talk To Security Team)](http://www.iishacks.com/index.php/2007/09/22/performance-tips-disable-logging-on-windows-server-iis/)

[Performance Tip](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2006/01/07/80510.aspx)

[Tune Up IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.05.resources.aspx)

[Tune Up IIS 2](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/71490aae-f444-443c-8b2a-520c2961408e.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 1):

Precompiling your ASP.NET application makes it faster. Release build is a plus.

Answer (score 1):

Some generic recommendations:

- Enable gzip compression
- Double check your images and optimize the images with editing software ex: save for web in Photoshop
- put your js files just before your body closing tags
- put your CSS in the head
- merge your js files into one file using the bundles in asp.net or manually
- merge your CSS with bundles or manually
- Make all small CSS and js inline instead of linked files
- important: MAKE SURE YOU SET THE CACHE SETTING PROPERLY
- use cdn if possible, ex: load jQuery from cdn and Google fonts from Google cdn.
- minimize your js,CSS html using online tools, no need for comments, whitespace, new lines ...
- use fonts for icons instead of images
- merge small images (icons ...) Into one image and use CSS spirit
- finally check your online site with Google pagespeed and yahoo YSlow

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In short yes, there are lots of ways you can improve performance of your application through iis settings. However your specific application will need its' own tuning.

The general hints are in the other posts. However there will also be some specific things about your application which can be tuned. For example if you have one or two directories which have a lot of activity compared to the rest of the site you can put them in separate application pools.

It is quite an art form and if after you have followed general advice here you are still having performance problems, I would recommend getting a consultant in for a week to tune things for you. Preferably one which can look at your ASP too.

The other thing you could do if you have specific choke points is to post queries on SO. There is only so far you can go with a generic advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://iistuner.codeplex.com/ it solved all of our problems regarding setting the config values in alot of places. It basically fixes all wierd and hard to find settings with one click.